# Autocomplete typeahead store user id into hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to store the user id into a hidden field (something like value="userid") so i can use it when i need to submit the from.
I've got a autocomplete field which is working fine but together with first and last name it shows also the user id.

This is what i've done so far:

The HTML form input

```
<input class="typeahead form-control" type="text">
```

The Javascript code

```
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
        return $.get('controllers/ctrl_prova.php', { query: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                return process(data);
            })

        }
    });
```

The PHP code

```
$select_user = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT user_id, user_first, user_last FROM users WHERE user_first LIKE '%".$_GET['query']."%' LIMIT 10");
mysqli_stmt_execute($select_user);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($select_user, $clientid, $clientfirstname, $clientlastname);
$json = [];
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($seleziona_utente)) {
$json[] = $clientfirstname.' '.$clientlastname.' '.$clientid;

}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Many thanks

Comment: You are concatenating `$clientid` in your `php` file along with `$clientfirstname.' '.$clientlastname`. That's the reason you can see the user_id.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Ok so if I remove $clientid from the concatenation it doen't show the user id in the input but I still don't know how to insert the user id inside the name="$clientid" into the input or maybe into a separate hidden input. Thanks

Comment: Is `process()` a custom function of yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to sort this out using jquery ui instead of typeahead. This is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ac_config = {
        source:'controllers/ctrl_inbox_client_search.php',
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        $('#id_cliente').val(ui.item.value); 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $("#clienti").val(ui.item.label); },    
        minLength:1
    };
    $("#clienti").autocomplete(ac_config);
});
```

Now the only problem i've got is the query to the database I need to select all the users with role ='admin' and all the users belonging to a specific group so I've used this query to the database

```
SELECT user_id, user_first, user_last, user_role FROM users WHERE user_role = 'admin' UNION ALL SELECT user_id, user_first, user_last, user_role FROM user_group_join LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON user_group_join . user_join_id = users . user_id WHERE user_group_join . group_join_id = 2 AND users . user_id NOT LIKE 59 AND user_role = 'client' AND users . user_first LIKE '%{$term}%' AND users . user_last LIKE '%{$term}%'
```

The problem is if a search for a user it shows also the admin even if their name is different from what i type in the search box. 
Can someone help me please?